# React-native app stuck on app:installDebug

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, android-studio

When trying to launch the project `react-native run-android` it gets stuck on

```
> Task :app:installDebug
07:59:09 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
<============-> 99% EXECUTING [2m 34s]
> IDLE
> IDLE
> :app:installDebug
> IDLE
```

I have already tried `adb kill-server && adb start-server` and  `cd android ./gradlew clean cd .. react-native run-android` and reinstalling node_modules nothing worked.

Comment: Try cold-boot of your emulator

Comment: How can I do that? I'm new to react-native and have been using VS Code

Comment: Quit your emulator, Open your android-studio > avd-manager > open your target-emulator > select cold boot now

Comment: It worked, it really worked, I have been having this issue for the past hours, thank you a lot.

Comment: Happy coding! ...